# Output of to_categorical: What does the fourth dimensions represent?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm building an autoencoder where I apply one hot encoding on the output of the encoder using `to_categorical`. The shape of my output is 5 dimensions: `(1000, 16, 16, 512, 1)`.

My input shape is `(1000, 16, 16, 1)` so I'm wondering what this additional `512` is?

For more context as to why I want to know, I want to feed the output of `to_categorical` into a bottleneck of shape: `bottleneck = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu')(reshaped_one_hot)` and I want to understand how to reshape the output of`to_categorical` to then feed it into this bottleneck.

Code:

```
encoder_img = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(16,16,1), name="input")
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1024, 1, activation='relu',kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.RandomUniform)(encoder_img)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(1)(x)
inputtothelayer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 1, activation='relu')(x)
pool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(1, name="thelayer")(inputtothelayer)
encoder = tf.keras.Model(inputs=encoder_img, outputs=pool, name = 'encoder')
encoder.summary()

layer_name = 'thelayer'
intermediate_layer_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=encoder_img,
                                 outputs=encoder.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(data)
print(intermediate_output)

one_hot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(intermediate_output,num_classes=None, dtype='float32')

bottleneck = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu')(one_hot)
```

Answer (score 1):

`to_categorical` is meant to transform "integer labels" into "one-hot encoded labels".

If you have an array from 0 to 9: `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`, the `to_categorical` result will be:

```
[
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
]
```

That said, it makes no sense to use `to_categorical` in a model's output. You are not outputting integer labels.

Comment: Does 'to_categorical' derive the categories based on the unique features of the input, similar to how sklearn describes one hot encoding in their [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html). (I'm carrying this out for a theory I have so my reasoning of why I'm doing things likely doesn't make sense to you). Essentially, I want to perform a one hot encoding where I'm not feeding in the categoricals. I wanted the model to find the categoricals given their unique characteristics like how sklearn describes it.

Comment: "Encode categorical `integer features` as a one-hot numeric array." -- Exactly the same.

Comment: Suppose it works and you pass floats to this function, you will end up with tons of meaningless classes, and the worst part, the function will not be differentiable, making everything non-trainable from `one_hot` forward.

Comment: That's fine, I'm taking the output of the bottleneck and feeding it to another algorithm else where - I just need the one hot encoding to be able to categorise everything into categoricals. Do you have any advice on fixing the above error. Instead of squeezing it, I've decided to just take certain indices of the array like such: `reshaped_one_hot = one_hot[:, :, :, 0] ` but I still get the ` TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' `